# Ralink rt3090 driver installed and wireless doesn't work on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: wireless

I have a LG A-410 lap-top (64 bits) with rt 3090 wireless card. Searching the problem I discover that I already have a rt 3090-dkms installed, but my wireless doesn't work.

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: RaLink
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e5400000-e540ffff
```

Comment: I've nuked a load of stuff that was only showing the wired network port. You can check [the revision log](http://askubuntu.com/posts/114955/revisions) if you want to see that.

Comment: @Marcus - please click the tick button next to the answer that is correct to close the question.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The hardware is not claimed by any driver.  First install the driver from [this site](http://stat.case.edu/~jrt32/how_to_build_rt3090_for_ubuntu_lucid/rt3090-dkms_2.3.1.4-0ubuntu0~ppa1_all.deb).

Then, from [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1490123.html), enter the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2860STA/
sudo touch /etc/Wireless/RT2860STA/RT2860STA.dat
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Now, list the hardware and see if it's claimed by the driver that we installed just above:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

In my case a reboot was needed.  (I might be missing some command here to avoid reboot, but it works for me)

My laptop:

1. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
2. HP Pavilion dv6

Comment: With the (blank) config file added, the driver may be picked up from the 10.04 staging area.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/541620) (that I suggest you read through) this is a problem with older kernels that has not been fixed in older releases like 10.04. It has been fixed in Natty and Onieric though so perhaps an update is an option.

One thing that is suggested does work for *some* users is using the package from the following PPA:

- https://launchpad.net/~markus-tisoft/+archive/rt3090

I can't say if it'll help but if it doesn't, you might want to consider an upgrade, or pulling in a newer kernel from [the Kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

Answer (score 0):

start add hardware search for drivers 
also try installing windows wireless drivers then add INF. file for the driver